# How can I get an image to be clicked and send that data through a form to JSON and mysql?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

I have a voting app, that is working but clicking a radio button and then submitted the form. However, I am trying to create a listener for the images that will register a click and send the variable to the same form submitted function called update_vote(). When I try to send the data through JSON, I can't decode the variable. When I try to add a listener, the variable isn't passed. So how can I send the image ID to php and mysql after it's been clicked like a form world do?

I believe that my json is trying too many things, and I have been using a modified version of a previous application that worked with json. I have since removed json and now trying to integrate back in using the event listener. After spending several hours, the farthest I got was getting the vote casted, but it doesn't refresh the page, is there something I missed or is it usually like this?

Top shows the POST form submitted, bottom shows the ajax code
index.php
START

```
<?php require_once("../resources/config.php");

if(isset($_POST['imageId'])){
echo $_POST['imageId'];
//update_vote($_POST['radio']);
    update_vote("63");

if(isset($_POST['radio'])){
    echo $_POST['radio'];
    echo "123";
    ?>

    <script>alert("NEW VOTE");</script><?php
    update_vote($_POST['radio']);
}

}
if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
    echo $_POST['name'];
//update_vote($_POST['radio']);
    update_vote($_POST['name']);

}
?>

<form method='post' action='index.php' id='editor'>

    <div class="row">



        <?php images(); ?>

        <input type=submit id="submitVote" name="imageId" value="VOTE"/>
    </div>

</form>
</div>
    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer class="py-5 bg-dark">
      <div class="container">
        <p class="m-0 text-center text-white">Copyright &copy; Your Website 2018</p>
      </div>
      <!-- /.container -->
    </footer>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vote.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
<script>
    $('a').click(function(){
        var src= $(this).find('img').attr('name');
        alert(src);
<!--        --> //update_vote( //'. );
        vote(src);


    });

</script>
```

END INDEX.php

NOTE: THAT CALLING THE UPDATE VOTE DIRECTLY HERE DOESNT WORK SINCE ITS A JAVASCRIPT VARIABLE

HERE IS THE functions.php and the vote.js

FUNCTIONS.php

```
function update_vote($image_id)
{
    echo "update";
    //get number of votes and update
    global $link;
    $data = array();
    $stmt = query("INSERT INTO votes (userID, imageID) VALUES ('1', '{$image_id}')");
    //mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $image_id);
    confirm($stmt);

}
function update_vote2()
{
    update_vote("63");
    echo "update";


}

/*
 * Get the images to show from a specified folder and show two models
 */
function images(){


    //
    $query = query("Select * from photos ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2");
    confirm($query);
    $x = 0;
    while($row = fetch_array($query)){
        $x++;
        $vote = <<<DELIMITER


        <div class="col-lg-6 portfolio-item">

            <div class="card h-100 w-100" style="text-align:center">
            <a href="#" id="a"><img name={$row['id']} style="max-height:400px; class="card-img-top" src="admin/images/{$row['filename']}" alt=""></a>

        <div class="card-body text-center">
            <h4 class="card-title">
            Model {$x}
    </h4>
        <input class="text-center" type="radio" name="radio" value={$row['id']}>

            </div>

            </div>

            </div>






            DELIMITER;

        echo $vote;

    }


}
```

vote.js

```
//ajax call to send upvote
function vote(name){
    var httpRequest;
    httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //console.log('')
    if (!httpRequest) {
        console.log('Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
        return false;
    }else{
        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = alertContents;
        httpRequest.open('POST', 'index.php', true);
        var data = "name="+encodeURIComponent(name);
        httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        //console.log(data);
        httpRequest.send(data);
    }
    function alertContents() {
        if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
                console.log(httpRequest.responseText);
                var data = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);

                if(data['imageID'] && data['new_amount']){
                    document.getElementById(data['imageID']).innerHTML = data['new_amount'];
                }
            } else {
                console.log('There was a problem with the request.');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have the voting working when clicked on the picture, but 1) when a form is submitted it refreshed the page smoothly, and ajax just sends the post without a refresh action, can I add that?
2) Ideally, I would like to call the php function onclick but that caused a lot of headache, I can't do that, right?

So the function currently runs, but doesn't change the images, which are supposed to show randomly after each vote.

Comment: you send the ajax to `index.php`. But index.php doesn't return any json, but a bunsh of testing echoes and some html. This is why `JSON.parse(responseText)` will fail.

Comment: You need to seperate the html/form/ui from the target for ajax. Have a seperate file that only respondes to your ajax call and returns _only_ a json. nothing else.